# ORACLE output of logical comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I would like to have output of logical comparison in oracle. In example below, output should be false, instead it throws error. I am coming from sql server world, where this is very simple. In oracle it's obviously quite different.

```
DECLARE
    test1 number := 1;
    test2 number := 2;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(test1 = test2);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression:

```
dbms_output.put_line(case when test1 = test2 then 1 else 0 end);
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=48864736a7352590f5cc668cc2390d99)**:

```
dbms_output:
0
```

Comment: Thanks for demo. Is begin - end block mandatory in oracle queries like this?

Comment: @FrenkyB: that's actually not a *query*, but an anonymous code block, for which, indeed, `begin/end` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI. I haven't written any serious Oracle for a couple years, but this question reminded me a a function I have laying around. It came in very handy debugging without a interactive debugger. Thought I'd share it.

```
create or replace function boolean_to_text(test_in boolean)
return varchar2
is
begin
  return case when test_in then 'true' 
              when not test_in then 'false' 
              else 'null'
         end ; 
end boolean_to_text;
```

Where "test_in" is any boolean expression. It works because the expression is evaluated before the function gets called.  Unfortunately, since Oracle has yet to support boolean data type in SQL it can only be used in plsql.

```
-- tests
begin 
  dbms_output.put_line( '1=1 is ' || boolean_to_text(1=1) ); 
  dbms_output.put_line( '1=0 is ' || boolean_to_text(1=0) );   
  dbms_output.put_line( 'a>b is ' || boolean_to_text('a'>'b'));
  dbms_output.put_line( 'True>False ' || boolean_to_text(true>false) ); 
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Sysdate> 2020-05-18 is ' || boolean_to_text(Sysdate> date '2020-05-18') );   
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Null=Null is ' || boolean_to_text(null=null) );  
end;
```